# Business Assets of Time Travel

Tags: economy, time-travel

So, if at one point in the future humanity discovered a new type of wormhole allowing them to travel to whatever time era they wanted, past or future, what could a large scale corporation feasibly take advantage of and use to earn money? (Disregarding money and etc.) This sort of thing could include anything from temporal tourism to prehistoric safaris to to even much less legal things like hiring to try to change the past or future. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I'm going to close vote his as too broad, because there are millions of ways to make money, all of which are possible by time-travel. Also, we don't know what method of time travel you're using, which is also important.

Comment: Second the close vote...need to know more on how time travel paradoxs are handled

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what theory of time travel you use to prevent a paradox.

1. Time travel can not change history because there is no difference between the past and the future. (Think "Terminator")

In this case, time travel could be used of research and tourism. They would be no worry about people change the past, because they can't.

2. Multiple Earth Theory, Part One: Every time you change the past you create a new timeline and original timeline is absorbed into the new one.
   (think "Back to the Future")

In this scenario time travel is probably illegal, but that won't stop those will to pay the right price. Imagine time traveling assassins or dictator from the future conquering the ancient world. the possibilities are endless.

3. Multiple Earth Theory, Part Two: Every time you change the past you create a new timeline and original timeline is not absorbed into the new one.

In this case nothing you do in the past will effect our timeline so the possibilities are endless. Trade modern weapons to the highest bidder in WWI? Why not? I sure there will be plenty of millionaires who will pay a lot of money to go back in time and take over the world. Eventually with every one that can make new timelines you would have your own multiverse (think "Endless Earths" book).

Comment: With type 1 (a timeline that obeys the [Novikov self-consistency principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle)), startups that would go on to be successful could also get loans from their future selves, making it easier for good business ideas to get off the ground. Another issue: would money exchanges between different eras be treated as different currencies due to issues like inflation, so that there'd be an exchange rate between money from one era and money from another, or would they be treated as identical if they were both from the same country?

Comment: @Hypnosifl That depends if people in the past know about time travel and how far in the past your take the money to

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no. I've seen it advanced as evidence *against* the existence of time travel, because such inter-time commerce would [drive interest rates to zero](https://books.google.com/books?id=39KQY1FnSfkC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=time+travel+interest+rates&source=bl&ots=EzgVfv1PNr&sig=4M83hiOPGKxA2MlyR50L1bdisWs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL7YeL78HMAhUD1h4KHcvnAx4Q6AEIJzAF#v=onepage&q=time%20travel%20interest%20rates&f=false).

Comment: You mean like how, just a few years ago, the idea of even suggesting that below-zero interest rates might be a real thing seemed outright preposterous?